# Regex: Match up to character, abort if contains word

Tags: regex

I have a document like

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "p_id_1", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updateable = false)

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "p_id_2", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

I am trying to design a regex that matches from `@ManyToOne` to `)` (excluded) but does not match if the line contains `, insertable`

After trying around I ended up with `@ManyToOne\n.+?(?=, insertable|\))` but this also matches a part of the first lines. What I want it to do is not matching the first two lines and the second two lines only up to the `)`

As a sidenote: I am using it in a Gradle-Build-Script written in Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use negative lookarounds to make sure the match breaks on encountering `, insertable`, and a positive lookahead to exclude the closing bracket, something like:

```
@ManyToOne\n((?!, insertable).)*?(?=\))
```